# BLOB 0 byte going in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was trying to insert blob in table obook I have coded this file for that purpose when this page is executed all works fine all the data update in the table obook except the blob containing column IMAGE there I get [blob-0byte]. Is there any syntax problem or the method Im using is wrong?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $id=$_SESSION['eid'];
    include("config.php");
    if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
    {
        $bn=$_REQUEST['bookname'];
        $pr=$_REQUEST['author'];
        $au=$_REQUEST['publisher'];
        $k=$_REQUEST['price'];
        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']));
        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO obook(BOOKNAME,AUTHOR,PUBLISHER,PRICE,SELLER,IMAGE) VALUES('$bn','$pr','$au','$k','$id','$image')"))
        {
            header("location:outofstock.html"); 
        }
        else
        {
            header("location:index.php");   
        }   
    }
    ?>
    <head>
        <title>POSTADD</title>
        <style>
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

        #main{
        width:960px;
        margin:50px auto;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        }

        h2{
        background-color: #FEFFED;
        text-align:center;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        margin: -10px -40px;
        padding: 15px;
        }

        hr{
        border:0;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        margin: 10px -40px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        #login{
        width:300px;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-family:raleway;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px 40px 25px;
        margin-top: 70px;
        }

        input[type=text],input[type=email]{
        width:99.5%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-left: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family:raleway;
        }

        input[type=submit]{
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#FFBC00;
        color: white;
        border: 2px solid #FFCB00;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size:20px;
        cursor:pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: -12px;
        }

        #formget{
        float:right;
        }
        h1 {
        margin-left: -85px;
        }
        </style>
        <style>
            table{
                border-spacing:15px;
            }
            td{
                padding:30px;
            }
             body
              {
                background-image: url(back.jpg);
                background-position:0px 0px;
        background-attachment:fixed;
            background-size: cover;
                background-repeat: repeat;
              }
            </style>
        <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #ff3333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #ff8080;
        }
        </style>
            <style>
        .center {
            margin: auto;
            width: 60%;
            padding: 100px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

</head>
    <body>

        <div class="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="index.php">NewBooks</a></li>
                <li><a href="oldbook.php">OldBooks</a></li>
                <li><a href="rentbook.php">Rent a book</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php?con=1">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">MyProfile</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <div id="main">

            <div id="login">
                <h2>Old books</h2>
                <hr/>
                <form name="f1" onSubmit="return vali() method="post">
                    <label>Book Name :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="bookname" id="bookname" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Book Name"/><br /><br />
                    <label>Author Name :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name of the Author"/><br/><br />
                    <label>Publication Name :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="publisher" id="publisher" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name of Puclications"/><br/><br />
                    <label>Price :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" required="required" placeholder="Please Price of the book"/><br/><br />
                    <label>Image :</label>
                    <input name="photo" type="file"  id="photo" /><br/><br />
                    <input type="submit" value=" send " name="send"/><br />
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Right side div -->

        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I would [recommend you view the comments on SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361215/php-dropdown-and-database)

Comment: From phptpoint and ofcourse google for refrence

Comment: Actually I have chaged thae code and now file get saved but its in .bin format